# Recess PHP framework Vs CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, recess

I haven't taken a look at Recess PHP Framework in a while, but for those that have experience with both frameworks I ask this question: What features does Recess offer over CakePHP 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the code in the [Recess github repository](https://github.com/recess/recess) hasn't seen an update in 3 years, with the latest commit a year ago. The forums are offline and their last blogpost dates back from 2010. So I'm not sure if Recess is actively developed anymore, which might become a problem in the long run.

That said, Cake has quite a lot of developers, is backed by a foundation and receives regular updates. Also Cake's ecosystem of plugins, code snippets, etc. is bound to be more extensive compared to Recess.